# Unable to switch directory in Azure Portal

Tags: azureportal

My work account (name@domain.com) was today added as a guest account in a new clients AAD, i.e. my account was mapped to a new tenant.

Whether relevant or not, this new organization require MFA (Multi Factor Auth), so I downloaded Micorsoft Authenticator App and mapped the tenant to my account. No problem.

When logging in to https://portal.azure.com I am directed to the new clients portal and after signing in (using MFA) I am presented with an error message in the Azure portal saying I lack permission to a subscription.

My problem is that I **now can´t switch directory / tenant in the Azure Portal**.
So I am effictively locked out from using Azure Portal.

I dare to say this is NOT a client / cache / cookie issue. I have tried clearing cache, even logging in from a browser using a fresh Win10 installation. Always ending up the new clients portal..

I have found [other posts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/243724/portalazurecom-redirects-me-to-former-client39s-po.html) describing the same problem, but not any solution that works for me.

Deleting the organization at https://myaccount.microsoft.com/organizations also fails, as I lack permission for this operation.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What about using ctrl+shift+N, then go to safe mode to login?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was, when presented with the error modal after logging in the Azure portal, to press F12 (dev tools), find the modal in html tree, and delete it.
After that I could change directory.